# Confused about the numer of voting members in a MongoDB replica set?

Tags: mongodb, database-replication

In the [replica set architecture](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-architectures/) article the suggested (minimum) configuration is made of: one primary member and two secondary ones (or one secondary and a lightweight arbiter). Hence **two voting members**.

However few lines below you can read (this is for having "smooth elections"):

> When adding additional members, ensure the following architectural
>   conditions are true:
>
> - The set has an odd number of voting members.
>
>   If you have an even number of voting members, deploy an arbiter to create an odd number.

If I'm right **two is even**, that is the suggested minimal configuration is wrong! How an even number of voters can cause elections that are "not smooth"? What's "not smooth" in terms of voting in the replica?

More on this: even counting the primary as voter (thus three voters, odd number) if the primary goes down you'll end up with two voters. How the primary can vote if it's down?

Comment: You have three votes in set you described.  If a member is down then it cannot vote.  That's like voting no, or abstaining.  To become a primary the secondary needs to get 2 (majority of three) yes votes.  Since it can get two votes, it'll become the new primary.

Answer (score 1):

> In the replica set architecture article the suggested (minimum)
>   configuration is made of: one primary member and two secondary ones
>   (or one secondary and a lightweight arbiter). Hence two voting
>   members.

This is incorrect.  Primary, secondary and arbiter is THREE votes.

Therefore you have an odd number of votes.  Therefore if one node is down the other two are a majority and can elect a new primary.

The reason you shouldn't have an even number is so that in case of a network partition you won't end up with 50% of voting members on each side of the network partition - if that happened you would have no primary even if every member of the replica set is actually up.

Comment: Can't still get it: if the primary goes down (using one master and two slaves) you'll end up with two voters. How the primary can vote if it's down? In addition, AFAIK a secondary become a new master by priority or freshness of the data: how the network partition could be a problem?

Comment: number of votes depends on total configured replica set, not how many are "up".  if you configure three nodes then three votes exist.  doesn't matter if one or two of them are down - that's equivalent to them not voting for the third one.

Comment: Forget my last comment, I wasn't thinking right though it does matter if two of them are down since then the quorum doesn't have a majority of voting members on line, I have tested that one for sure; even posted about it in the forums and scot confirmed it was because there was not a majority of the configured replicas on line to vote...